# Load buildConfigField String from remote TXT file ( Android APP Java)

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

So, I'm not experienced in Android App's as i'm trying to learn.

On build.graddle app module I have this string I need to change every week, the issue is that to change that String I need to roll out an app update every week.
This is the code in USe

```
    buildConfigField "String", "GAMEID_1", "\"1_gameID\""
```

Is it possible to have  "1_gameID\ be loaded from a remote URL where I can replace it with another ID?

Comment: BuildConfigs are generated at build time, what you want is something similar to remote configs.  As an example, you can look at firebase remote config.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config

Comment: Can I randomize it? Can i add for example 1_gameID , 2_gameid, 3_gameId, so it randomly picks one of these 3 without remote config?